# Find the last entry for specific user id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to find the last entry for a specific **user** for each **location**. I also need to ignore any rows where the **balance** is zero.

Sample table:

```
    ID location user balance
    -- -------- ---- -------
     1 GLA      A    10.21
     2 GLA      A    0.00
     3 GLA      B    45.68
     4 GLA      B    12.56
     5 EDI      C    1.23
     6 EDI      D    5.48
     7 EDI      D    0.00
     8 LON      E    78.59
     9 MAN      F    0.00
    10 MAN      F    12.98
    11 MAN      G    56.45
    12 MAN      G    89.25
    13 MAN      H    0.00
    14 BIR      I    0.00
    15 BIR      I    32.87
```

Result required:

```
    ID location user balance
    -- -------- ---- -------
     4 GLA      B    12.56
     5 EDI      C    1.23
     8 LON      E    78.59
    10 MAN      F    12.98
    12 MAN      G    89.25
    15 BIR      I    32.87
```

I have been left to cover for a colleague who is off sick and unfotunately my SQL knowledge is limited in comparison.

I have been researching using MAX and PARTITION BY but with no luck so far. This is for a SQL Server 2005 database.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. I will add any progress I make.

Many Thanks.

Comment: *‘I also need to ignore any rows where the balance is zero’* – you mean you need to ignore users whose **last** `balance` is zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `row_number()` to get the result:

```
select id, location, [user], balance
from 
(
  select id, location, [user], balance,
    row_number() over(partition by location, [user]
                        order by id desc) seq
  from yourtable
) d
where seq = 1
  and balance <> 0
order by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2bd1/15)

Comment: I think you would want the `balance <> 0` inside the sub-select so that you do not lose the `A` User in your fiddle.

Comment: @AdamWenger That is what I thought initially but based on the desired result that would be wrong.  It looks like the logic is return the max id for user/location as long as the balance is not zero.  If you place that inside the subquery user A will be returned which is not what the OP desired above.

Comment: @AdamWenger No. This query is correct, the `balance <> 0` should be in the outer query. According to the OP, users `A`, `D` and `H` should be excluded because their **last** balance is zero. +1

Comment: @bluefeet, I just read the desired results again - you are correct. +1

Comment: @bluefeet thank you very much this worked perfectly. This experience has inspired me to hit the books and learn more about SQL.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select   
      A.ID ,
      A.location,
      A.[user] ,
      A.balance from TABLE1 A 
     inner join (
                 Select Max(Id) AS Id from TABLE1 
                 group by location,[user]
                 ) B 
      on A.ID=B.ID 
      WHERE A.Balance>0
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72cc3/2)

Comment: OP wants grouped by location **and by user**. Also you forgot to exclude the zero balances

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos now it's ok

Comment: For SQL Server, User is a keyword so refer to that identifier using: [user]

Comment: @MichaelJSwart nowits ok

Comment: Thank you for your input, this also provided the required result.

Comment: @user2637680 your most welcome dont forget to accept as answer if it help u to solve ur problem and you think it best one among all

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) Function:

```
SELECT id,
   location,
   user,
   balance
FROM   ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER( )
              OVER (
                PARTITION BY user
                ORDER BY id DESC ) AS rowid,
            *
     FROM   tableA ) AS data
WHERE  ( rowid = 1 )
   AND ( balance > 0 )
```